# Symfony (2.8): what is a spooled email and why the email is not sended?

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

Firts, sorry about my english :(

I need help about spooled emails. My App send an email, but I don't recived it. The debug talks about a "spooled" email. What is it? It's the problem?.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html, this will explain the concept of spooled mails in Symfony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official documentation:

> The default behavior of the Symfony mailer is to send the email messages immediately. You may, however, want to avoid the performance hit of the communication to the email server, which could cause the user to wait for the next page to load while the email is sending. This can be avoided by choosing to "spool" the emails instead of sending them directly.
>
> This makes the mailer to not attempt to send the email message but
>   instead save it somewhere such as a file. Another process can then
>   read from the spool and take care of sending the emails in the spool.
>   Currently only spooling to file or memory is supported.

You can read more about it, especially how to configure spool, [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email/spool.html)

Comment: But I'm using the send() function.... and symfony spooled it. The result of send() is 1 (true), but the email is not recived.

Comment: It will be true because for symfony it's expected behaviour, it means that mail was successfully saved in memory or in some directory, please check if there is some 'spool' parameter in your config for swiftmailer

Comment: thanks for the answer :). In my config there are:  spool: { type: memory }. But I use the send() in differents functions on my app, but only one function spooled the emails. It's possible to see the spooled queue by commands? (similar to swiftmailer:spool:send ??). Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: According to the documentation:

_When you use spooling to store the emails to memory, they will get sent right before the kernel terminates. This means the email only gets sent if the whole request got executed without any unhandled exception or any errors._

So I suggest you to carefully inspect this function for errors or maybe not appropriate parameters, etc. Also try to remove spool and see what happens, but still according to documentation there are some problems in your code

Comment: OMG! solved! I hat a "die()" in my controller in order to test de functions. This die() spooled ALL my emails jajajaja. I lost 2 days.